# Getting the UITextField that's associated with my observer

Tags: objective-c

I've got an observer on my UItextFields. It basically looks to see if the "enabled" property has changed.

If the enabled status changes, I want a method called fade to run. Fade requires a TextField to be passed to it.

How do I use the textField associated with the Observer that sends the message?

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:     (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *) context;
{
    int new = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    int old = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];

    if (new != old)
    {
        [self fadeEnable:"requires txtField"];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the Docs,
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html, the parameter 'Object' in the method call encapsulates your textfield.
you just have to cast it and youre done.

To cast it, use:

```
UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)object;
```

Edit to address your follow-up Question:
In The case of a Gesture recognizer, you want to get the view that you added the recognizer to. The 'sender' being the recognizer itself, sender.view will get you the associated view.
None of this will ever change, because recognizers only work with VIEWS.

Now, with an observer, you do not necessarily want a view. You want an OBJECT. Thats why 'object' is of type 'id', so you can add observers to objects of arbitrary types. The downside is, of course, that you need a cast. If you dont know what type to cast to, the

```
-isKindOfClass:
```

method might be useful.

Oh, and none of this is about interface-builder versus doing stuff in code.

If you find this confusing, i suggest you go study the docs on gestureRecognizers and Key-Value-Observing. If you have specific questions, let me know, or just ask an new question ;)

Comment: I actually tried that but mistakenly used UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)object.view; It was based on what i used to get the UITextField of my Gesture recogniser UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)sender.view; Why does it require the .view part for the Gesture recogniser and not the Observer? Is it because the Gesture recogniser has been added in the interface builder?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this really helped clear things up for me.